# Our WSUS accidentally had Windows Insider updates turned on. How can I remove the 1909 update from my Windows Update screen without installing it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-insider, wsus

There was a misconfiguration in my company WSUS and Windows Insider updates were accidentally included (our sysadmin checked the box for all Windows components and apparently Windows Insider was a part of that). I'm the only user with a Windows 10 machine (small shop of half a dozen people), and as such, my Windows Update recommends I install the 1909 feature update. Note that this machine is not enrolled in Windows Insider, has never been enrolled in Windows Insider and is not planned to ever be enrolled in Windows Insider. I'm not the sysadmin. Note that we use our WSUS only as a database of available updates, not to also distribute the updates themselves. We download the Windows updates themselves from the official Microsoft servers.

Our sysadmin has unchecked the Windows Insider box, but I still got that "Evaluation version of Windows Insider component update to version 1909 x64" update in my Windows update list. I've tried hiding the update through that one troubleshooting thing you can download, I've tried restarting the Windows Update service and I've tried deleting my SoftwareDistribution folder, but I can't figure out how to make this update go away. I've clicked the option to pause the updates for 7 days, but I don't know what else to do. I really don't want to accidentally install this update and then end up with an evaluation edition of Windows 10 1909 meant for betatesters.

Comment: Have you tried to [Remove a Windows update using WSUS](https://www.geekshangout.com/wsus-how-to-remove-an-update-from-computers/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned in my question that I paused updates for 7 days. I just resumed the looking for updates, and it checked for updates again and didn't find the Windows Insider update again (this was after our Sysadmin disabled the Windows insider box).

So I managed to solve my problem (how to remove the 1909 update from Windows 10 Windows Update settings screen without installing it) by first pausing Windows Updates for 7 days and then resuming the Windows updates immediately afterwards. This triggers a new search for Windows updates and indeed uses the new WSUS configuration for updates. Because at this point the Windows Insider updates were turned off, it didn't recommend it again during this check.

Comment: Don't add this as an answer, add it to your question.

Comment: Or edit it into a clearer answer, right now it looks like a comment.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Is this better?